# How does attr_accessor know that :player = @player?

Tags: ruby, instance, instance-variables, attr-accessor

Here's the code:

```
class Dungeon   
  attr_accessor :player 
    def initialize(player_name)   
    @player = Player.new(player_name)   
    end 
end
```

Now, if I write:

```
dungeon = Dungeon.new("Robert")
puts dungeon.player.name
```

it's obviously going to spit out `Robert`.

I'm a little new to Ruby, so forgive me if this question is obvious to you all. I'm struggling to wrap my head around it still. I am learning about "instance", "class", and global variables and my question is: How does Ruby know that `:player` in the code above refers to `@player`? Why isn't the code written, instead, `:@player`?

Does that make any sense?

Comment: the `@` character is not actually part of the symbol, it just indicates that `player` is an instance variable and not a local variable.

Comment: You're going to find, as you learn different languages, that some things are voodoo and black-magic. This is one of those things. The internal workings of Ruby define `attr_accessor` to map a symbol, like `:player`, to point to an instance variable `@player` that is defined in that class. It might not help a lot, but just accept that as it is, it's how Ruby was written to work.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` is just a method that defines a public getter/setter. `@player` is the actual instance variable that stores values. The getter it generates is based on the symbol name, so `:player` creates these methods:

```
def player
  @player
end

def player=(player)
  @player = player
end
```

If you only want the getter you can use `attr_reader`. If you only want the setter you can use `attr_writer`. `attr_accessor` combines these two methods and gives you both methods.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is easy to overlook when first learning Ruby is that the construct

```
attr_accessor :property_name
```

is just a shorter way of writing getter and setter methods for a class's instance variables:

```
# getter
def property_name
  @property_name
end

# setter
def property_name=( some_value )
  @property_name = some_value
end
```

It's basically an example of the "metaprogramming" support in Ruby, but it feels like something more mysterious.

Also, you do not have to use the symbol style, you could instead have:

```
attr_accessor "property_name"
```

The symbol version just "reads better" for most people.